# Font-awesome 5 not working

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, truetype, woff

I decided it was time for me to switch to Font-awesome 5 when I ran into a problem. My icons are not shown. It shows me this. [image]

I don't get where the problem occurs. I followed every step on their site and linked the files correctly but they still dont show. Here is a screenshot of the file.

[image]

What is causing this? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  IMAGES of code are not acceptable.

Comment: the `net::ERR_ABORTED` response should only occur when a user interaction interrupts the request. I'd recommend disabling any browser plugins and any javascript that might be interfering with the request.

Comment: try to use this href just for testing `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css`

Comment: @SpaceDogCS It works fine with that link. But I dont want to use a CDN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lets add all.min.css to css directory then link it

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.min.css">
```

and make webfonts directory beside all the main folders

Answer (score 4):

You can use cdn link for fontawsome,its a better way. Please see the below code, it may help you

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-10x" ></i>
```

Comment: Why the hell was this down voated? Because someone at font awesome wants to collect email addresses? This works

Comment: or via js `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the absolute path by adding another / in the start of your import methods.

Are you sure that you only need to import the minified css? You might need to import the fonts too.

The error on your console shows that the problem you're facing is import related.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. Even If I import every file. It still does not show if I do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're getting the .CSS from `/fontawesome`. FA will then try to load its fonts from `/webfonts` - I assume this does not exist.

I'd recommend to stick with FA's folder-structure. Move the .CSS to `/fontawesome/css` and make sure you copy the `webfonts-with-css/webfonts`-folder into `/fontawesome/webfonts`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had a directory called fontawesome into which I put fontawesome-all.css and the webfonts  directory.

I simply changed it to placing the directory structure by adding a subdirectory css, moving the .css file to it and changing the link to include the subdirectory.

Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

An simple solution.

1. Download the files from #fontawesome for #web

[image: Download the files from #fontawesome for #web]

2. Your html

[image: Your html]

3. Your browser screen

[image: Your browser screen]

Answer (score -1):

it's `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-10x" ></i>` not `<i class="fas fa-camera-retro fa-10x" ></i> </pre>`

Comment: Not in FA 5. They changed the prefix -- https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4#icon-name-changes

Answer (score -1):

your problem is 'fa' and not 'fas'

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-10x" ></i>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. `fa´ist FA4 - the `fas` refers to FA5's solid-style and is perfectly valid. See https://fontawesome.com/icons/camera-retro?style=solid